# jQuery's hover() event is not good for locating mouse position. Any fix?

Tags: jquery

You see, when you try to get the mouse position from jQuery's hover() event, you get the point at which the mouse enters the target area, not the point at which the mouse stops after entering the target area. Html's title property handles the situation correctly by showing the tooltip at the stop location, not the point of entry. Is there any way we can locate the stop location?

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jF27b/

Answer (score 2):

See the jQuery tutorials on [Mouse Position](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
</script>
```

You can use `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` to get the position of the mouse, and then get the element's X and Y, and use that to get local X and Y of the element.

Comment: Hi the mousemove event is pretty much useless

Comment: If you observe how html's title attribute behaves, you will find the tooltip does not follow you inside the target area every time you move the mouse.

Comment: @Aperture: Detect the time the mouse stops with a timeout. It's not "pretty much useless".